# CakePHP3でselect sum()の値を取得したいのですが

Tags: cakephp

こんにちは。CakePHP3 で家計簿を作るにあたって、買ったものの金額の合計値を出せるようにしたいと思っています。

公式マニュアルを見ながら、 `select sum` の値を書いたのですが、結果ではなく発行された SQL そのものが出てしまいます。
なぜなのでしょうか...。

```
//Householdscontroller.php
public function index()
{
    //db作ってbakeしたもの
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Tags']
    ];
    $this->set('households', $this->paginate($this->Households));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['households']);

    //合計金額を出す処理
    $query = $this->Households->find();
    $amount = $query
            ->where(['status' => 'out'])
            ->select(['sum' => $query->func()->sum('payment')]);
    $this->set('amount', $amount);
}
```

`$amount` の部分を view で見てみると、

```
SELECT (SUM(payment)) FROM households Households WHERE status = :c0
```

と出ています。SQL ではなく数字が欲しいです。

ちなみにこの from 以下が二つある理由もよくわからないのですが、
phpMyAdmin でそのまま実行してみたら値は無事取得できていました。

Answer (score -1):

$amount->first()、または、$amount->all()としてみてください。
それでentityが取れるので$entity->sumとかで合計値が取れると思います。
連想配列が取りたい場合は->toArray()で取れます。